# Command to stop and restart serverless

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I know I can use this command to deploy my api functions

```
sudo serverless deploy -s <stag>
```

I need to stop this service and restart it again. What is the command for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If removing and redeploying the service is an option, then you can use

```
sudo serverless remove -s <stag>
sudo serverless deploy -s <stag>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is right? I will be in trouble if something gets wrong. My job is in your hand

Comment: Uhmm no, your job is in your hand. No one here will be responsible for what you're doing. But you can read more about serverless here https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/